# How can I avoid excel changing referenced cell values when source is reordered

Tags: microsoft-excel

here's what I want to do:

1. Copy values with a link to a number of cells from sheet1 to sheet2 (i.e. the cell in sheet2 shows something like ='sheet1'!E2)
2. Filter or Re-order source data in sheet1 and copy a different range of cells from sheet1 to sheet2

When I filter/re-order the source data in sheet1, the values I have already copied to sheet2 change accordingly. However, I need the values in sheet2 to stay the same, regardless of how I filter the source data on sheet1.

I could just copy and paste the values, but I need them to be linked so that I can update cell values on sheet1 and they update on sheet2.

How can I ensure that regardless of where cell values end up on sheet1, they still show the same on sheet2?

I've tried using $, but that seems to have no affect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you used a `$`, you probably used it wrong. The $Alpha$number is static. It shouldn't change. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static reference: A1 is dynamic, it changes. $A$1 is static. It won't change even if you copy/paste/sort. So in your case chage `='sheet1'!E2` to `='sheet1'!$E$2`